# can spring container XML config reference use another bean'property

Tags: java, spring, configuration, javabeans

Here I am writing a  spring application, here I want to do is like this:

```
   <bean id="sqlClient"  class="com.braoda.dao.sqclient.SqlclientWapper">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.braoda.dao.user.UserDaoImpl">
  <property name="sqlSession" ref="***sqlClient.SqlSessionFactoryBean***" />
```

As the code like, I want use the spring Xml property config from "ref", but "ref" is not a    bean but a bean's property.
  is this illegal in spring or we can not use spring like this.

Comment: here i don't use the SqlSessionFactoryBean in the Spring context XML because the datasource doesn't get its full info, when the application start, I will get the datasource info from the Configuration Center(which is a configuration management we develop use Zookeeper ).  SO I will wait the Spring context inited,and get the info from center then we new the SqlSessionFactoryBean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

have a look at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/35869-reference-bean-property-within-reference

which shows code like  `<property name="username" value="${local.username}"/>`

Comment: yep， it dose work. here is my spring configuration:   
   <bean id="userDao" class="com.braoda.bsp.gene.datasource.sample.UserDaoImpl" scope="prototype">
     <property name="sqlSessionFactory" value="#{sqlMapClient.getSqlSessionFactory()}"/>
   </bean>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the `#{...}` notation:

```
<property name="sqlSessionFactory" value="#{sqlMapClient.getSqlSessionFactory()}"/>
```

Note:

- `${...}` may be used to substitute Spring **property names** for their value
- `#{...}` may be used to let Spring evaluate **expressions**

More details at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html.